# Apply CSS to a containing div when child is focused

Tags: html, css

I am performing some `:focus` changes when a user tabs through a site, and am trying to add an outline of `2px solid #F3692B;` to the parent `li`, when the `<a>` tag is focused when the user tabs through the site.

This is the HTML:

```
<li class="panel activePage" style="width: 1038px; height: 340px;">
    <a href="/about" class="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <img src="/sites/distribution.jpg" alt="Digital" class="active">
    </a>
</li>
```

I know there is CSS to change the properties of a containing div and adjacent div, but I have not been able to find any way to change the CSS of a parent div.

Keep in mind I do NOT want to use jQuery for this!

Any suggestions?

Comment: **...not been able to find any way to change the CSS of a parent** because you have been finding something which does not exist. There is no way to select parent in CSS (at this time).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks @KingKing I was unsure if I was not looking properly or if it did not exist

Comment: There are currently no parent selectors. Only child and sibling selectors. Do you have a use case that can better describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: well if you want to select a parent on focus, you will have to use script. if not jQuery, then plain-vanilla JS or something else.

Comment: What if you changed your markup? Example: http://jsbin.com/xemuyiye/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would be ideal... BUT... If you're just using the li as a container, then why don't you apply the focus outline to the anchor tag instead of the list item and apply a tab index to the anchors?

```
<style>
li.panel { width:1038px; height:340px; }
li.panel a { width:100%; height:100%; }
.active { outline:#00FF00 dotted thick; }
</style>

<ul>    
<li class="panel">
    <a href=""><img src="" alt="" class="active" tabindex="1"></a>
</li>
<li class="panel">
    <a href=""><img src="" alt="" tabindex="2"></a>
</li>
<li class="panel">
    <a href=""><img src="" alt="" tabindex="3"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently several browsers started to support [:focus-within](https://caniuse.com/#search=focus-within) pseudo-class.

But it is still not fully supported in all browsers.